# Confusion Regarding the Derivation for Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a hard time figuring out why the highlighted angles are also $\theta$. I understand that those velocity vectors are perpendicular to the circle's radius, but I still don't see how to arrive at that relationship for $\theta$.

[image]

Comment: Which "relationship for $\theta$" are you referring to?

Comment: @Gert I was saying that I don't understand how we know that the highlighted angles are θ

Comment: I'll answer that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Angles]

In the trigonometrical situation above, **the black $\theta$ and the red $\theta$ are identical** because:

1. $OA$ is perpendicular to $O'A'$ and,
2. $OB$ is perpendicular to $O'B'$.

One could formally prove that but for angles different from $\pi/4$ it's visually obvious.